# How to add pagination codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to add pagination codeigniter ?

I tryed to use like this link, but it doesn't work
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/pagination-in-codeigniter/

thank you for help me.

Comment: use codeigniter's default library

Comment: you mean this link https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html right?

Comment: yes thats library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pagination is one of the libraries in the codeigniter...

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 20;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

you can get reference from here... https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also manage pagination manually, it can be easier sometimes depending on what you do: let's say you want batches of 100 results per page, pass a page_number parameter to your controller, then

```
$results_limit = 100;
$offset = 0;
if (isset($_GET['page_number']))
    $offset = ($_GET['page_number']-1) * $results_limit;
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('sltax_tax_name');
$this->db->order_by("t_id", "desc");
$this->db->limit($offset, $results_limit);
$query = $this->db->get();
// grab your results...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use Pagination class from CodeIgniter rather than doing it manually.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html

In Controller

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/test/page/';
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 20;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

In the view

```
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```