# pagination related array list

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have an array list which contains the list of product details like  product_name qty, price, address, while inquiry of page this result is going to display then I need to apply pagination of that list of array of the same product but the different seller.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [seller_name] => 'tiger'
            [product_name] => 'rice'
            [price] => 2100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [seller_name] => 'lion'
            [product_name] => 'rice'
            [price] => 18500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [seller_name] => 'human'
            [product_name] => 'rice'
            [price] =>27500
        )

)
```

So on I need here pagination for fetching more related seller data for the same product... in code-igniter.

list of array list to display.

Comment: did you read: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html ?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847607/how-to-add-pagination-codeigniter